# Correct way to resize an image and append to HTML form?

Tags: javascript, forms, image, post, resize

I'm trying to resize an image client-side before submitting a form and then appending it to the form. When I submit this initially it seems to be working correctly. But on the server-side it's still uploading the original. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this post only now while solving the same problem.
It is NOT POSSIBLE to replace the user selected input of type 'file' with a resized one. For security reasons browsers do not allow this.
The form is posted using HTTP POST which is synchronous. According to some articles, altered image should be posted asynchronously. All examples use XHR or Ajax for this.
Possible solution seems to be like this:
1) Resize the image and convert canvas to dataUrl or blob;
2) Either add a new hidden field to your form or move image upload outside the form;
3) Use XHR or Ajax to post the resized image;
4) Either remove name attribute from the original input of 'file' type (this will prevent its submission) or ignore server-side;
5) On a server decode dataUrl and save the image in your upload folder.